# Rails: Communicating between RSpec helper modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, rspec, travis-ci

I would be very grateful for some advice on the following.

Below I have a simplified example for our setup.

I have defined some Helper modules on our RSpec test suite:

```
## spec/rails_helper.rb

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ViewHelpers
end



### spec/support/view_helpers/base.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

module ViewHelpers
  class Base
    # class content
  end
end



### spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

module ViewHelpers
  module Admins
    module Payments
      class New < Base
        # class content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this setup the specs run perfectly locally; the sub-class `New` inherits from `Base` as expected. However, when the tests are running on Travis CI, we get the following error:

```
NameError:
1433  uninitialized constant ViewHelpers::Admins::Payments::Base
1434# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:6:in `<module:Payments>'
1435# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:5:in `<module:Admins>'
1436# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:4:in `<module:ViewHelpers>'
1437# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
1438# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
1439# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `each'
1440# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
1441# ./spec/controllers/admins/billpayers_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have also tried inheriting with explicit namespacing:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ViewHelpers
  module Admins
    module Payments
      class New < ViewHelpers::Base
        # class content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Again, this runs successfully locally but Travis CI errors:

```
NameError:
1433  uninitialized constant ViewHelpers::Base
1434# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:6:in `<module:Payments>'
1435# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:5:in `<module:Admins>'
1436# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:4:in `<module:ViewHelpers>'
1437# ./spec/support/view_helpers/admins/payments/new.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
1438# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
1439# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `each'
1440# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
1441# ./spec/controllers/admins/billpayers_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am rather stumped as to why this works locally but not on CI.
Would be very grateful for any support and insight.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you double checked your autoload configurations? (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Autoload and cache classes may be configured differently based on your environment configs:

```
├── config/environments
    ├── development.rb
    ├── production.rb
    └── test.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the ordering of

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")]
```

depends on the OS and filesystem.

This means the sub-classes were getting required before the super-class.

Solution:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].sort
```